# create a table with specifc documents

Tags: r, ggplot2, cut

I am trying to create a ggplot graphic using the tokenised.clean.Rda document I created. This document is a dataframe of tokenised words with two columns (first with the name of the document (doc_id) and second with the word (word)). This same document works fine when I create a graphic with the whole of the table.
To do so, first I create a grouped df with three columns (first "period", second "words" and thrid "n".
However, I want to create the same graphic with fewer rows (using only the rows up to 1955 the only thing that happens is that when the table arrives to the documents with the name which contains a number superior to 1955, it erases the doc_id column and still uses the other two columns ("words" and "n").

```
table.until.1955 <- tokenised.clean %>% 
  mutate(year = str_extract(doc_id, "\\d{4}"), 
         year = as.numeric(year),
         period = cut(year,c(0, 1919, 1929, 1939, 1945, 1955),
                      labels = c("1913-1919", "1920-1929", "1930-1939", 
                                 "1940-1945", "1946-1955"))) %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  count(words) %>% 
  filter(n> 25)
```

I thank you for your time and understanding

Edit nº1:
since the dataframe is quite big (63.3 Mb, more than 3 million observations, and 2 columns) copying and pasting the output of dput here is not a solution. I however did as follows (I hope that helps):

```
test <- dput(tokenised.clean)
head(test)
```

being this the output (the same as `head(tokenised.clean)`

```
> head(test)
readtext object consisting of 6 documents and 0 docvars.
# Description: df [6 × 3]
  doc_id       words    text     
  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>    
1 AR-1913-1914 annual   "\"\"..."
2 AR-1913-1914 report   "\"\"..."
3 AR-1913-1914 tee      "\"\"..."
4 AR-1913-1914 rokri    "\"\"..."
5 AR-1913-1914 library  "\"\"..."
6 AR-1913-1914 broadway "\"\"..."
```

Best regards

Edit nº2
I added the filter code line :

```
table.until.1955 <- tokenised.clean %>% 
  mutate(year = str_extract(doc_id, "\\d{4}"), 
         year = as.numeric(year),
         filter(doc_id %in% paste0("AR-",c("1913-1914",1915:1955))),
         period = cut(year,c(0, 1919, 1929, 1939, 1945, 1955),
                      labels = c("1913-1919", "1920-1929", "1930-1939", 
                                 "1940-1945", "1946-1955"))) %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  count(words) %>% 
  filter(n> 25)
```

However I get this error message:

```
rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..3 = filter(doc_id %in% paste0("AR-",
  c("1913-1914", 1915:1955)))`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"
---
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% filter(n > 25)
 10. dplyr::filter(doc_id %in% paste0("AR-", c("1913-1914", 1915:1955)))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..3 = filter(doc_id %in% paste0("AR-",
  c("1913-1914", 1915:1955)))`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% filter(n > 25)
  2. ├─dplyr::filter(., n > 25)
  3. ├─dplyr::count(., words)
  4. ├─dplyr::group_by(., period)
  5. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  6. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  7. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
  8. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  9. │   └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 10. ├─dplyr::filter(doc_id %in% paste0("AR-", c("1913-1914", 1915:1955)))
 11. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 12.   └─dplyr h(simpleError(msg, call))
 13.     └─rlang::abort(...)
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput()`?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to share the data using dput().

Comment: Take your name of your data frame in dput(df) and copy paste the output of console in your question

Comment: the object is quite big (63,3 Mb and 3 million observations) so is not handy to copy-paste the output. I did however test <- dput(tokenised.clean) and then head(test). I copy-paste the head(test) on the question.

Comment: Hi! I see in your code you are creating labels for periods using cut, but I don't see you filtering your data according to a rule (year <= 1955, for example).  Is that right? Otherwise you'll just have all your data, but a bunch of it unlabelled.